# .NET Seed with hashed password

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to seed my default users with already hashed passwords instead of plain text passwords in either code or environment variables.

Is there a suitable way ?

Running .Net 6 and Code First Approach.

Comment: What problem are you facing? How are you seeding your users now?

Comment: Since hashes are by design one way you need to generate a plain text password and hash that. If the password is static you could simply hash the password by using a separate tool, and copy the hash to your seed data.

Comment: are you referring to the properties to be used by core entity framework?

Comment: Are you referring to seeding your default users when the database is created? In that case, you can use "IEntityTypeConfiguration" you can seed the data you want.